# Python: How to implement the @ operator for my own class

Tags: python, matrix, operator-keyword, matrix-multiplication

I am currently making my own matrix class with some methods and wanted to implement matrix multiplication. I've seen it implemented in numpy and wanted to ask if it is possible to use it with my own class aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `@` operator by overriding the `__matmul__` method (and possibly `__rmatmul__` as well). Override `__imatmul__` if you want to support `@=` as well.

For more information, read about the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), specifically the section on [emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).